# mysql insert query with subselect. prevent error when foreign key is empty

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, constraints

I've got this query which is giving me some problems in mysql.

```
insert into `stat`
  (`match_id`, `team_id`, `value`)
values
  (1,
  (select `match`.`team_a_id` from `match` where `match_id` = 1),
  123)
on duplicate key update value = 123;
```

Relevant information:

- both tables are innodb
- column `stat`.`team_id` can not be null.

The problem:
Sometimes the team_id is null in the match table. This causes a constraint violation:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'team_id' cannot be null
```

Which is good, because we do not want records without a value in the column team_id.

I prefer not to run a separate query to fetch the team_id, as this query is executed **a lot**.

How can I adjust this query in such a way that when `match`.`team_a_id` is null :

- no error is thrown
- no record is inserted in the stats-table.

Or to put it in english:

- do not insert a record in the stats table when the team is not known.

note: I removed some unrelated columns from the query/tables to make it more compact for the question.

Comment: Why dont you just check if `(select `match`.`team_a_id` from `match` where `match_id` = 1)` is NULL or not and then do insert? If you had a unique index on team_id you could make use if `INSERT IGNORE INTO` but im guessing there is no unique index on that column?

Comment: It is one consideration which is currently used as a fix. This requires sending an extra query to the database however. which causes the code running to be quite slow and we need it to perform. At peak times this query is probably run up to 30-50 times a second. As I currently think there is no solution for this in sql, we probably end up using some caching on the code-side.

Comment: If it doesnt change that often it may be worth to cache the query in mysql. Since its a FK and it sometimes is null, you must check the value before insert, i cannot think of another way.